# Azure Pipelines - Triggering pipeline on push from another repo with the correct branch being used

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure git code repo where I keep my code and a separate Azure git pipeline repo where I keep my pipelines. Both are in the same project so the pipeline repo can reference the code repo. I have set it up so that when someone pushes code to the code repo, a build pipeline is triggered in the pipeline repo. There I have encountered the following problem:

I have 3 branches for each repo: test1, test2, main. I only using test1 and test2 for the pipelines. When I push code to the test1 branch of code repo, I want the pipeline from test1 branch of pipeline repo to fire, and similar for test2 branch.

Right now this is not the case, when I push code to the test1 branch of code repo, the pipeline from main branch of pipeline repo fires. This pipeline then correctly checks out the test1 version of the code from code repo, which is good. This is still a problem because I then have different deployment pipelines on each branch set up to trigger on the end of these pipelines, and right now this won't happen because it's not the pipeline from test1 branch completing, but rather the pipeline from main branch. Same issue with test2 branch.

This is what the resources part of YAML looks like on the different branches:

test1:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyRepo
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyRepo
    ref: test1
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - test1
        - test2
        exclude:
          - main
```

test2:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyRepo
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyRepo
    ref: test2
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - test1
        - test2
        exclude:
          - main
```

main:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyRepo
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyRepo
    ref: main
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - test1
        - test2
        exclude:
          - main
```

I have had a similar problem when triggering a deployment pipeline from a build pipeline resource, and there the solution was to set the default branch for manual and scheduled deployments in the YAML section of triggers. Here I have set it to test1 but it did not help.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same wit you.

Tested on my side, the repository resource is only worked on the pipeline yaml which defined on `main` branch(default), it doesn't work on the other branches.

To achieve your expectation, as an alternative, you can use classic release pipeline instead. Setting as below:

1. Add `two repos` and select the `default branch` which will be checked out.
   [image]
2. Set the `trigger` on one repo, enable `CI` trigger with target branch.
   [image]

Commit on code repo `test1` branch, it will download the `two repos`(source) with target branch in release pipeline automatically.
[image]

Create a new release pipeline which monitor on target code repo with branch `test2`, similar steps as above. So commit on code repo `test1`,`test2` branch will trigger the pipeline as expected.

Comment: Thanks, it's a shame it can't be done with YAML. I've ended up modifying the entire approach a little bit since I want to stick with YAML but that you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome! :) currently it's a limitation that repository resource trigger only works on the pipeline yaml which defined on the `default` branch.